# What if I don't connect all the GND pins on the USB Type-C

Tags: usb

Do I need to connect all the GND pins (A12, B1, B12, A1) to their respective pads or will it work just fine with only pins B12 and A1 (which are on the opposite side)?

I'm asking this because I don't have the space for pads A12 and B1... and yes I'm already using a small receptacle (USB 2.0 Type-C with 16 pins). Thank you.

Comment: How big are the traces to the pads you do have and how much current will you be running?

Comment: @KH traces are 10 mils since this USB Type-C receptacle have narrow pads (10.5 mils). By the way it's a macro keypad (5V).

Comment: To be clear, I don't have enough experience with these to answer your question, but the fellow who does will want to know what your load is.  It would be best if you take a screenshot of your circuit board laid out the way you want to and add it to your question.  When you add additional information to your question, do it by clicking "edit" at the bottom of your question though, not in the comments.  This saves time for our talented volunteers and ensures the information is not lost in a site cleanup.  You can still @ someone in a comment to tell them you've updated.  Provide datasheet links.